# Sqlite in Adobe Air, Data type mismatch

Tags: javascript, sqlite, air

I've been using Adobe Air framework (with JavaScript) and a sqlite 3 database. Everything worked fined, but after a while the Db started throwing Data type mismatch: could not convert text value to numeric value errors. As best I can recall, I've done no modification to either the database schema or the JS code. The SQL command is the following:

```
UPDATE products_original SET purchase_id='7894', sold_qty=sold_qty+1 WHERE id='11786'
```

Interestingly, when using an external program to connect to the sqlite database, the same command doesn't throw an error.
Could you please help me with this issue?

EDIT: The columns are all INTEGER types.

Comment: Not using apostrophes in the sql command still generates the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Adobe air sqlite is very strict about data types if you have inserted data like strings in integer column from external tools it will throw these kind of errors. Check if data in your table follows the datatypes you have assigned to each column

Comment: That's true. Also, check the editor you are using for your SQLite operations. SQLite Manager for example, messes up datatypes for some reason. Very annoying.